# syntax: doing binary_search (STL) for sorted vector of pointers to struct

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, stl, binary-search

sorry if this is a noobish question but even after reading a bunch of documentation and forum posts I just can't seem to get this to compile:

Basically, I've got this struct:

```
struct Entry{
    unsigned long long time;
    // other things...
};
```

And I've successfully created a `vector<Entry*> timestampSearch`.

timestampSearch has been sorted, and I'm pretty sure successfully, based on the member variable `unsigned long long time` in each of the objects of type `Entry` that each of the elements of `timestampSearch` point to.

FWIW, it was sorted via `<algorithm>`'s std::sort function, using this predicate:

```
// time compare predicate/functor to sort by timestamp   
struct cmp_time_cat_entryID{
    inline bool operator() (Entry* entry1, Entry* entry2) const{
        if (entry1->time == entry2->time){
            if (entry1->category_lower == entry2->category_lower){
                return (entry1->entryID < entry2->entryID);
            }
            else{
                return (entry1->category_lower < entry2->category_lower);
            }
        }
        return (entry1->time < entry2->time);
    }
};
```

...and called like this:

```
sort(timestampSearch.begin(), timestampSearch.end(), cmp_time_cat_entryID());
```

So, when it came time to binary_search timestampSearch, I had figured the syntax for calling STL binary_search would be very similar to STL sort, and tried to call it like so:

```
    bool time1present = false;
    unsigned long long time1 = 0425215422

    time1present = binary_search(timestampSearch.begin(),
                                   timestampSearch.end(),
                                   time1, 
                                   cmp_time());
```

...with a very similar predicate that might (?) save on a few cycles:

```
struct cmp_time{
    inline bool operator() (Entry* entry1, Entry* entry2) const{
        return (entry1->time == entry2->time);
    }
};
```

However, I'm getting this compile error:

```
    Error   1   error C2664: 
'bool cmp_time::operator ()(Entry *,Entry *) const' : 
cannot convert argument 1 from 'const unsigned __int64' to 'Entry *'

c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\algorithm    2666    1   test_unordered_map
```

Can anyone help me fix this and get binary_search working?

Answer (score 1):

Your binary search comparison function compares between `Entry` object whereas you are passing an `unsigned long long` type (which cannot be converted to `Entry*`).

Create a new instance of `Entry` object (which is to be searched) and pass it to the `binary_search` function or create the appropriate comparison function.

```
bool operator()(unsigned long long time, const Entry* ob)
{
    return time == ob->time ;
}
```

In C++11 and above, you can also use a lambda expression as the comparison function.